# Rails where model has all assocations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `Note` who `has_and_belongs_to_many:` `Tags`.

I want to find all Notes who have at least both tags with ID `1` and `2`.

Currently, I have this:

`Note.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: [1,2] }).references(:tags)`

This will return all `Notes` that have a tag with EITHER ID `1` or `2`.

I want to return any note that has both tags. It can have more than just those two tags, but it has to at least have both of those two.

Any thoughts? I am using Rails 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found a good solution for this. But I'm sharing my solution in case you don't find a good one. You can do it like this,

```
Note.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: 1 }).references(:tags) && Note.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: 2 }).references(:tags)
```

Surprisingly **it costs only one sql query** and it works. You can write a method that will make a chain like this depending on your array and then use `eval` to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Could try using SQL syntax in your where call?

perhaps something like:

```
Note.includes(:tags).where('EXISTS(SELECT 1 from tags where id = 1 and note_id = notes.id) and EXISTS(select 1 from tags where id = 2 and note_id = notes.id)').references(:tags).uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain 2 wheres

```
.where(tags: { id: 1 }).where(tags: { id: 2 })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can Chain two where Tags very easily.

```
Note.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: 1 }).where(tags: { id: 2 }).references(:tags)
```